# Same output but doesn't work

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm currently developing an app for android and i'm new to it. I'm using SQLITE database. I have retrieve the String and get the String from EditText, however the log says that both strings that I retrieve is "test" but when I used the if else statement, it returns different

```
if(editText.getText().toString()==myCursor.getString(myDB.COLUMN_NAME_ID).toString())
 {
  Log.i("String","same");
 }
else
 {
  Log.i("String","diff");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing Strings in Java:

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

More detailed information and discussions can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1970317